# Importing and Exporting LyX files with AMS environments

Tags: lyx, amsmath, amsthm

I'm having some trouble converting LyX files that use AMS environments back and forth between the .lyx format and the .tex format. To see what I mean, here is a minimal example.

Starting with the following raw LyX file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-ams-bytype
theorems-sec-bytype
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "charter" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize letterpaper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 0.5in
\topmargin 0.75in
\rightmargin 0.5in
\bottommargin 0.75in
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip bigskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Definition
Sample Text.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

I used File > Export > LaTeX (plain) to generate the following .tex file:

```
%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.75in,bmargin=0.75in,lmargin=0.5in,rmargin=0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{defn}{\protect\definitionname}[section]

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
  \providecommand{\definitionname}{Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
Sample Text.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

So far, so good, as both files compile to the same .pdf file. Unfortunately, when I try to import the .tex file back into LyX, the AMS environment disappears and I am left with some ERT:

[image]

And while trying to compile in LyX, I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment defn undefined.
```

It looks like during the import process, the following lines were removed:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{defn}{\protect\definitionname}[section]
```

Trying to stick this code back into the preamble results in an 'Undefined control sequence' error.

Is this behaviour expected for LyX 2.2.3 or have I missed something here? If possible, I would like to preserve all of the AMS environments throughout the conversion process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, great first post! Lots of details and code -> +1. Second, it's usually not a good idea to continually do back-and-forth with LyX import/export. LyX does not have great import of TeX format (this is actually a very complicated problem to solve so it will not improve a lot). As for getting ERT, that is a known problem: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10432  But as for compile problems, I don't know if that is known. I suggest you  report that on trac: https://www.lyx.org/trac (be sure to select the component "tex2lyx")

Comment: I have similar opinions with @scott. Not a good practice to export/ import back and forth between  LyX and LaTeX. I would recommend to export to LaTeX occasionally and compile it with good old LaTeX (or pdfLaTeX) and make sure it is working.   LyX is not universal but LaTeX is and will always be.

Comment: This is because you're using AMS modules. Not sure they're recognized as such when importing back from LaTeX. Anyway, there are three commands missing `\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{defn}{\protect\definitionname}[section] \providecommand{\definitionname}{Definition}`. Maybe you can stop using the modules, and rely on ERT and some preamble code.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback, guys!
  
  
I did a bit more experimenting, and it looks like part of the problem is that I'm using a Theorem (AMS) module that seems to conflict with tex2lyx, specifically the one that enumerates by type AND within sections.
  
  
Oddly enough, if I just have it enumerate within sections, the conversion is perfect! I will, however, follow your advice and try to keep the conversions between TeX and LyX minimal.


As for opening a ticket, I think I'll leave it alone until the main problem with tex2lyx is resolved.
  
  
Thanks again, everyone!